# PHP: Retrieving and displaying (in HTML) most recent image file in folder

Tags: html, scandir

I would like to scan a folder, sort the files within that folder by modified time, and display the most recent file. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

function scanDir ($dir){

    $fileTimeArray = array();

    // Scan directory and get each file date
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $fileTime){
        $fileTimeArray[$fileTime] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $fileTime);  
    }

    //Sort file times
    $fileTimeArray = arsort($fileTimeArray);

    return($fileTimeArray[0]);
}

?>
```

I'm calling this function in another php file, within the src of an img tag.

As of now

```
<img src=Array>
```

Where am I going wrong within the function? Thank you!!!